# Como configurar el ejecutable de php en visual studio code en ubuntu...si tngo instalado el xampp?

Tags: php

me encuentro con este problema, tengo instalado el xampp, visual code en ubunto...cuando abro un archivo .php me aparece un error que no se configura el executablePath..intente con usr/bin/php y no me funciona...

"php.validate.executablePath": "???"

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema q tu , me pudes indicar como lo resolviste.. si solo copiaste la linea de codigo que te dio este comando="whereis php" en el visual o escribiste algun otro comando .. por favor , ya que no me resulto... Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Usas Linux? Prueba con "whereis php" desde una shell.
Si es Windows, utiliza el buscador y busca la ruta completa de "php.exe"

Comment: Si uso linux...hice lo que dijiste y me funcionó...Gracias por tu aporte

Comment: A mi tambien me funcionó... lo unico es que a mi me salian dos rutas: `/etc/php` y `/opt/lampp/bin/php`. Como en la respuesta de *gjaurena* ponia que era la segunda, esa fue la que utilizé y me funcionó. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso con linux fedora 38 funcionó agregando el path

```
"/opt/lampp/bin/php"
```

para la clave: `php.validate.executablePath`